# Spring 3 form binding object is always null

Tags: java, jsp, forms, spring-mvc, spring-3

I'm trying to bind a nested object with Spring 3, and I'm having issues.

**JSP:**

```
<portlet:actionURL var="formAction" />
<form:form id="add-objects-form" method="post" action="${formAction}">
   <input name = "obj.a"...>
   <input name = "obj.b"...>
   <input type = "file" multiple="multiple" name="file"/>
</form>
```

**Form Object:**

```
class FormObject{
private final static Logger logger = ...

private MultipartFile file
private Obj obj

...getters and setters
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadDocument(@ModelAttribute FormObject formObject, BindingResult results ) {

}
```

`formObject` gets `obj.a` and `obj.b`, but `file` is always null.

Comment: Have you set something like @SessionAttributes("formObject") in the controller class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `modelAttribute="formObject"` in `<form:form>`

Also make sure you haven't excluded debug information from classes. If you have, or you are uncertain, specify `@ModelAttribute("formObject")`

For handling files (multipart data) you need to specify the enctype for the form:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Update: since you are using a js-library for fileupload, here's what to do:

- upload only picture with ajax request (don't submit anything else). Store the uploaded files in a temporary location
- the response will possibly contain the names of the temp files. Store these names in a hidden field
- then submit the form (either via ajax or via regular submit), and pass the value of the hidden field, which now contains only strings
- move the files from the temporary location to a permanent location
- files that have been uploaded, but without the form being submitted, can be cleaned by some hourly/daily job.

Comment: I have a nested object, and obj does not have `files`.

Comment: I tried both of these together, but I'll try again :/. This doesn't seem like it should be too difficult. I am posting to the action via AJAX, however, so maybe that's related.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall perhaps it does make a difference. Can you cehck with firebug how does the POST request look like?

Comment: The other fields are binding now, but `file` is still null. Firebug shows the post body as the file content.

Comment: No dice. I'm getting a tomcat exception now about cannot convert "String" to "MultipartFile". The data is in the response body, but it doesn't bind.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall - I'm not sure how spring is supposed to mention multiple="multiple". Try without it firist, following the manual: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: I can't try without it. I'm using the ajax file uploader library here: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: @Stefan Kendall well, please include this information in your question, I'll update my answer. I happen to be using the same library, and I'll explain how ;)